# Intel VTune command line error

Tags: windows, cmd, intel, intel-vtune

I am trying to use VTune command line to set maximum number of samples to be collected before the collection stops. For this I have using the -msc command but I get an error saying unknown command.

The command I am using is : "C:\Program Files\Intel\VTune Amplifier XE 2015\bin32\amplxe-cl" -collect general-exploration --duration 30 -msc 300

The above command gives me "Unknown command -msc" error

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

VTune command line tool can't do what you requested. VTune can't limit collection time based on number of collected samples

I can suggest to decrease collection time (-duration) or decrease amount of data to be collected using -data-limit option.

BTW 
The list of supported options can be obtained by following command 
amplxe-cl -help collect
List of supported analysis type specific knobs can be obtained this way
amplxe-cl -help collect general-exploration